# Strange "NA.123" rows in an R data frame

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, na

I am having a very strange issue with R. Some actions produce NA records in a dataframe that aren't "real" NAs -- they don't have a row in the original dataset, the row ID says something strange like NA.123 instead of a real row number, and they match a test of ==1.

It's hard to describe what is happening, so I'll let heavily-commented code do most of the talking. The data file referenced here is a small (187 K) publicly-available file from the NHANES 2005 datasets, available at http://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2005-2006/COT_D.XPT if anyone wants it so they can try to replicate the problem.

I am creating a yes/no variable to assess whether a cotinine blood test was positive or negative, using a cutoff of 10 to define a positive test. In the code below I do this two different ways, creating "cotpos1" and "cotpos2" to illustrate some of what I have found when troubleshooting this issue.

For the purpose of this post, a "good NA" is something that should be NA because the original blood test results were missing, and a "bad NA" is one of the mystery rows that wasn't part of the original data, every value is NA (including the SEQN, which isn't missing for any row in the original data), the row number shows up as something like NA.123, and the NAs in each column match ==1.

This dataset uses a field called SEQN to identify every record. At the start, no records are without a SEQN, so when the "bad NAs" appear later and their SEQNs are NA too (as well as everything else in the row) this suggests to me that rows are being added.

There are other ways I can do this that don't produce "bad NAs", like using ifelse() or using a package that does recodes, so my question isn't about how to make this work - it's "Why do the methods used in the code below produce the strange NA.123 rows?"

```
library(foreign) # To open SAS xpt files

# Read in the data files
testdata <- read.xport('COT_D.xpt')

################# cotpos1, everything set to 0 or 1 #################

testdata$cotpos1[testdata$LBXCOT >= 10] <- 1 # Positive cotinine test
testdata$cotpos1[testdata$LBXCOT < 10] <- 0 # Negative cotinine test

testdata$cotpos1[testdata$cotpos1==1] # We have NAs that match ==1
testdata[testdata$cotpos1==1,c("SEQN","cotpos1")] # The bad NAs have no SEQN and their row numbers look like NA.988
testdata[is.na(testdata$cotpos1),c("SEQN","cotpos1")] # The good NAs (ones that are NA because LBXCOT was NA, and match is.na()) have SEQN and row numbers

################# cotpos2, with initialization to 0 #################

testdata$cotpos2 <- 0 # Assume everyone is negative until found otherwise
testdata$cotpos2[testdata$LBXCOT >= 10] <- 1 # Positive cotinine test

# 3 tests to show we have no "bad NAs" at this point
testdata$cotpos2[testdata$cotpos2==1] # No NAs that match ==1
testdata[testdata$cotpos2==1,c("SEQN","cotpos2")] # No lines with no SEQN values or strange row IDs like NA.988
testdata[is.na(testdata$cotpos2),c("SEQN","cotpos2")] # No good NAs either because we initialized everyone to 0

# Now let's try finding the "good NA"s and setting them to NA (since they were initialized to 0, which is not accurate if the blood test results were actually missing)
testdata$cotpos2[is.na(testdata$LBXCOT)] <- NA

# Re-run the three tests, and they now show the bad NAs are back as well
testdata$cotpos2[testdata$cotpos2==1] # Now there are NAs that match ==1
testdata[testdata$cotpos2==1,c("SEQN","cotpos2")] # Now there are lines with NA SEQN values and strange row IDs like NA.988
testdata[is.na(testdata$cotpos2),c("SEQN","cotpos2")] # These are the "good NAs" only, the bad ones don't show up here
```

There are other ways I can do this that don't produce "bad NAs", like using ifelse() or using a package that does recodes, so my question isn't about how to make this work - it's "Why do the methods used in the code above produce the strange NA.988 rows?"

Further information in response to BondedDust:
Thank you for your reply. Can you please clarify which quirk of [] you are referring to?

I am aware of the quirk where if you feed it an NA, you get an all NA row, eg:

```
b = testdata$cotpos1==1
b
testdata[b,c("SEQN","cotpos1")]
```

then anywhere b is NA I should expect the last line to return an NA. Is that the one you are referring to? Unfortunately, with my code, the problem is that the weird NA rows are showing up in places where b wasn’t NA, so that quirk would not explain it.

Here are the last lines of b:

```
[8725]  TRUE    NA FALSE FALSE    NA  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA
[8737] FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[8749]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Here are the last lines of testdata[b,c("SEQN","cotpos1")]:

```
8711   41422       1
NA.986    NA      NA
NA.987    NA      NA
8722   41437       1
8725   41440       1
NA.988    NA      NA
NA.989    NA      NA
8730   41447       1
NA.990    NA      NA
NA.991    NA      NA
8742   41461       1
8748   41468       1
8749   41469       1
8751   41472       1
```

The strange NAs are showing up in places where b was not NA

Final edit:
BondedDust's reply was correct. When I was saying b and the strange NAs don't match up (above), I was failing to account for the fact that [] doesn't print rows corresponding to FALSE. Once you take the falses out, they match up perfectly.

Comment: I'm guessing you are seeing what I consider to be an infelicity with the R "[" function. Others, including the R Core, consider this to be a feature. If you select rows of a dataframe ( or values from a vector) with a vector that contains NA values, you get an line (or single value)  of NA's at that level/row-whatever in the result. You should learn to trim your dataset so they are a "minimal" reproducible example.

Comment: Presumably also goes away with `dplyr`, `data.table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the values of testdata$cotpos2 you see:

```
> table( testdata$cotpos2==1, useNA="always")

FALSE  TRUE  <NA> 
 6346  1415   992
```

Read the help page for the "[" function. It bears reading about 10 times. You should find the section which describes the behavior of "[" when given an NA-value. whenUnderstanding its rules and subtleties is key to effective data management in R. (I would have designed it differently with respect to the handling of NA values.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please clarify which quirk of [] you were referring to?

I am aware of the one where if you feed it c(TRUE,TRUE,NA,TRUE) it will return an all NA row for the NAs, the problem is that these all-NA rows are appearing in places where the result of testdata$cotpos1==1 is *not* NA. Since there is a character limit on the comments, I have added an example of this to the original question above.

Comment: ...aaaand I just realized your answer is correct and my reading of it is wrong.

When I count backwards to compare cotpos2==1 and the results from [], I should only count the "TRUE"s, the "FALSE"s aren't displayed because they're false. Counted that way, they match up exactly, so it is that quirk of []. Thank you!

Comment: Please state what specific quirk of "["? Otherwise this is not an answer.

Comment: I thought the "quirk" which I was calling an infelicity was fully described in the comment. This "answer" was really offered in hopes that it would be seen as proof of the validity of the analysis in the comment.

Comment: smci - the quirk/infelicity BondedDust was talking about is that if you feed [] an NA it will return one of the mystery rows. So if I had a == that evaluates to NA (as NA==1 does) then the results would be an all-NA row, even if the original row had data in other fields. BondedDust's answer was enough to point me in the right direction, and I have accepted it as the answer because it helped me solve the problem. Thank you both!